# How to install System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs for .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, nuget, nuget-package

I need to use System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs for that I have found following command to install Nuget Package.
Install-Package System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs -Version 4.4.0 with 4.5

When I execute this from PM. it shows error as 
Could not install package 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs 4.4.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: The message itself is clear enough. That NuGet package is not supported on .NET Framework 4.5, but on 4.6 and above.

Comment: yeah but my dependent project strictly runs on 4.5 only so I cannot change project framework

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .NET Framework 4.5 you shouldn't need the `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs` package, as it only contains types already in .NET Framework, in `System.Security.dll`.

Here's the entirety of the net46 implementation of the library, per ildasm:

```
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicAttributeObject
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicAttributeObjectCollection
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicAttributeObjectEnumerator
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.AlgorithmIdentifier
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsRecipient
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsRecipientCollection
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsRecipientEnumerator
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.EnvelopedCms
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.KeyAgreeRecipientInfo
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.KeyTransRecipientInfo
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.Pkcs9AttributeObject
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.Pkcs9ContentType
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.Pkcs9DocumentDescription
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.Pkcs9DocumentName
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.Pkcs9MessageDigest
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.Pkcs9SigningTime
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.PublicKeyInfo
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.RecipientInfo
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.RecipientInfoCollection
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.RecipientInfoEnumerator
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.RecipientInfoType
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SubjectIdentifier
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SubjectIdentifierOrKey
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SubjectIdentifierOrKeyType
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SubjectIdentifierType
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
.class extern forwarder System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.X509IssuerSerial
{
  .assembly extern System.Security
}
```

If you're needing to interoperate with something using .NET Standard you need to upgrade to at least .NET Framework 4.6, because no cryptography types are defined prior to .NET Standard 1.3 (which aligns to .NET Framework 4.6)

Comment: Thanks for update. Separated two projects. one is with 4.5 and other with 4.6.2 as service model bridge is already there between these two. thanks once again